# Throwing validation exceptions - with line numbers

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am mapping a JSON string to a POJO with no problems. The POJO constructor places a few validation constraints in place (an integer property must be positive, etc.), and throws an IllegalArgumentException.

I endeavour to present this with the line number of the offending data (or its context, say the parent JSON object}, in much the same way that a JSON syntax error is presented.

My investigations suggest this is not trivial, but it it possible?

M.

Comment: How about CustomSerializer? http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization - You can override the JSON Exception messages in your custom serializer

Comment: I am de-serialising a POJO, so a CustomSerializer isn't the ticket.

Comment: Have you tried deserializer then? I will give it a try tonight .. http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: A custom deserialiser works well except for properties that also map to POJOs, e.g. {someInt: 42, somePOJO:{name:"foo"}} mapping someInt is easy, but mapping somePOJO to my POJO.class eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can get the access to the parser location information in the deserializer. You should register a [deserializer modifier](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializerModifier.html) which would wrap the standard desiralizer(s) and catch creation exceptions. Inside the exception handler you will be to able add the location information to the exception object.

Here is a complete example:

```
public class JacksonLocationInException {
    public static class Bean {
        public final String field;

        @JsonCreator
        public Bean(@JsonProperty("field") final String field) {
            if ("invalid".equals(field)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field is invalid");
            }
            this.field = field;
        }
    }

    private static class DelegatingJsonDeserializer extends DelegatingDeserializer {

        public DelegatingJsonDeserializer(final JsonDeserializer<?> delegatee) {
            super(delegatee);
        }

        @Override
        protected JsonDeserializer<?> newDelegatingInstance(
                final JsonDeserializer<?> newDelegatee) {
            return this._delegatee;
        }

        @Override
        public Object deserialize(final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException {
            try {
                return super.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
            } catch (final JsonMappingException e) {
                throw new JsonMappingException(e.getMessage(), jp.getCurrentLocation(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class MyBeanDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {
        @Override
        public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(
                final DeserializationConfig config,
                final BeanDescription beanDesc,
                final JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
            return new DelegatingJsonDeserializer(deserializer);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new MyBeanDeserializerModifier());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        final String json = "{          " +
                "\"field\":\"invalid\"}";
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Bean.class));
    }

}
```

Here is the output containing the line and column number:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class stackoverflow.JacksonLocationInException$Bean] value failed: Field is invalid (through reference chain: stackoverflow.Bean["field"])
 at [Source: {          "field":"invalid"}; line: 1, column: 30]
    at stackoverflow.JacksonLocationInException$DelegatingJsonDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonLocationInException.java:52)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3562)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2578)
    at stackoverflow.JacksonLocationInException.main(JacksonLocationInException.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class stackoverflow.JacksonLocationInException$Bean] value failed: Field is invalid (through reference chain: stackoverflow.Bean["field"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.wrapException(StdValueInstantiator.java:396)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:231)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.build(PropertyBasedCreator.java:167)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:386)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1073)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DelegatingDeserializer.deserialize(DelegatingDeserializer.java:108)
    at stackoverflow.JacksonLocationInException$DelegatingJsonDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonLocationInException.java:50)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field is invalid
    at stackoverflow.JacksonLocationInException$Bean.<init>(JacksonLocationInException.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:227)
    ... 15 more
```